# AMI linux is compatible with what linux flavors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

Amazon AMI supports which linux flavors? I want to build a .so file which is compatible with Lambda Execution Environment(4.4.51-40.69.amzn1.x86_64
). I tried to build .so file on RHEL 5 as well as on Ubuntu. But After bundling this in java deployment package, lambda shows unsatisfied link exception. So I want to know which linux architecture is compatible with AWS lambda execution environment so that i can embed my .so(native lib) files in it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Seeing this is your first time here, please review this FAQ regarding on asking question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Enjoy your stay!

Please include details that might help other users answer your questions such as what methods have you tried or what is the expected result or errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "Amazon AMI"? I think you have Amazon Linux (a version of Linux maintained by Amazon) confused with EC2 AMI (Amazon Machine Images) which are like backups of EC2 servers.

Answer (score 1):

From [Lambda Execution Environment and Available Libraries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html):

> The underlying AWS Lambda execution environment is based on the following:
>
> - Public **Amazon Linux AMI** version (AMI name: `amzn-ami-hvm-2017.03.1.20170812-x86_64-gp2`).
> - Linux kernel version – 4.4.51-40.69.amzn1.x86_64